Explicit example of a set of coset representatives of $U(n)$ within $O(2n)$
I understand how to identify a unitary group $U(n)$ with the elements of the orthogonal group $O(2n)$ which commute with a linear complex structure $J$. I am also aware of the "two-out-of-three" property. I know from Eschenburg's Lecture Notes on Symmetric Spaces that $O(2n)/U(n)\cong O(2n)\cap A(2n)$ where $A(2n)$ are the skew-symmetric matrices.
I want to understand more concretely how the elements of the orthogonal group $O(2n)$ can be thought of as products of elements of the symmetric space $O(2n)/U(n)$ and the unitary group $U(n)$.
In particular, what is an explicit example of a set of left coset representatives of $U(n)$ within $O(2n)$? And likewise, what would be an explicit example of right coset representatives?
I imagine that I am asking for a parametrization.  I suppose this is a question about Klein geometry.
Thank you for helping me!

It's unclear what you mean by "constituted from" or the meaning of "are" in the phrase "what are the left cosets" is, but $O(2n)/U(n)$ can be identified with the space of complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, at least.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you. I am aware of that, and am studying Eschenburg's lecture notes https://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/symspace.pdf where he discusses this example. But I want to understand what are the left cosets of $U(n)$ within $O(2n)$? What is in such a coset? How can I describe it? In particular, if $o_1,o_2\in O(2n)$, when is it that $o_1U(n)=o_2U(n)$? How many cosets are there? And what is in them? What is known about that?

It is again unclear what you mean. Are you asking for the definition of a coset? $o_1 U(n) = o_2 U(n)$ exactly when $o_2^{-1} o_1 \in U(n)$, by definition. The cosets form a manifold of dimension $\dim O(2n) - \dim U(n)$ and in particular there are uncountably many of them. They consist, by definition, of translates of $U(n)$ in $O(2n)$.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you. I have rewritten my question to make it more clear that I am looking for a set of coset representatives.

I found the answer I want in the Wikipedia article on homogeneous space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space "In general, if $X$ is a homogeneous space of $G$, and $H_o$ is the stabilizer of some marked point $o$ in $X$ (a choice of origin), the points of $X$ correspond to the left cosets $G/H_o$, and the marked point $o$ corresponds to the coset of the identity."  I will think what that means specifically here.

That's a completely general statement, it doesn't tell you anything you haven't already stated here. This is just how we identify the space of complex structures with the coset space $O(2n)/U(n)$; it is a homogeneous space for $O(2n)$, meaning that $O(2n)$ acts transitively, and the stabilizer of the standard complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (this is the "marked point") $J$ is $U(n)$. It does not help you find a set of coset representatives at all.
